# Most general form of boundary condition for similarity solution to exist

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the heat equation $u_t-u_{xx}=0$ on the positive real line with initial conditions $u(x,0)=0$ and boundary conditions $u(0,t)=g(t)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}u(x,t)=0$ for $t>0$.

I am consider the scalings
$$
t=\epsilon^a\bar{t}, \ x=\epsilon^b\bar{x}, \ u=\epsilon^c\bar{u}.
$$
For the problem to be invariant under this scaling we must have $a=2b$.

I want to work out the most general form of $g(t)$ such that under a suitable choice of $a\neq0,b,c$ the problem is invariant.